Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: this.authService.roles.include is not a function
I am implementing role-based access control in my Angular application using guards. Specifically, I want to protect certain routes based on user roles. However, I'm encountering errors in my authentication guard implementation.
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {ActivatedRouteSnapshot, CanActivate, Router, RouterStateSnapshot, UrlTree} from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import {AuthentificationService} from "../services/authentification.service";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthorizationGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private authService : AuthentificationService, private router : Router) {
  }

  canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
    if(this.authService.roles.include("ADMIN")){
      return true;
    }else{
      this.router.navigateByUrl("/admin/notAuthorized")
      return false;
    }

  }

}

core.mjs:8400 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: this.authService.roles.include is not a function
TypeError: this.authService.roles.include is not a function

please do a console.log(this.authService.roles) and share the result, it should be an array only then includes exists to call it!

Yes, when I change it to 'includes', it works. Thanks!
